# How to decode/encode string to base64 in typescript express server

Tags: typescript, express, base64

I have an express server written in typescript.

As `atob()` or `btoa()` works on browsers, on Nodejs.

We generally use

`Buffer.from("some-string").toString('base64')` to encode string to base64.

However, this doesn't seem to work when I am writing the code in TypeScript. I need some help with this.

Comment: this article may help: https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/

Answer (score 44):

in Node typescript:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";

const b64 = "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==";
const str = 'Hello, World!'

const decode = (str: string):string => Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('binary');
const encode = (str: string):string => Buffer.from(str, 'binary').toString('base64');

test('base64 decode', () => {
  expect(decode(b64)).toEqual(str)
});

test('base64 decode', () => {
  expect(encode(str)).toEqual(b64)
});

test('base64 encode/decode', () => {
  expect(decode(encode(str))).toEqual(str)
});
```

Answer (score 27):

Please Use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) for encode string

```js
console.log(btoa("abc")); // YWJj
```

use for [atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) decode the same string

```js
console.log(atob("YWJj")); // abc
```

Comment: atob() or btoa() is throwing an error as btoa is not defined. I guess this works if you are hosting this on a browser. However, as a REST server, this might not work.

Comment: I understand the issue with whether or not this runs in a browser. My solution is browser-based and this worked really nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @deprecated — Use Buffer.from(data, 'base64') instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have used `window.btoa(fileData)` on the front end.

*NOTE: After the feedback from [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) and also reading the package code, it seems that you can just do it manually. However I had to run it twice to work.

I was also trying to decode a large image.*

Then on the nodejs server you can use Buffer directly:

```
const b64 = "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==";
const fileDataProcessed = Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString('binary')
const decodedData = Buffer(fileDataProcessed, 'base64')

// This is the code that you can now upload to your s3 bucket, or somewhere else.
console.log(decodedData);
```

Comment: There really is no reason to use a 3rd party package.

Comment: @zerkms If you're not using a 3rd party package, how do you do it?

Comment: `Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString()`

Comment: You're right. However I had to pass it through twice.
I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm really confused - if you need a string you can do `Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString('binary')`. If you need a buffer - you do `Buffer.from(b64, 'base64')`. What's the point of `const decodedData = Buffer(fileDataProcessed, 'base64')`? It produces garbage 

Comment: My use case is to upload the image to AWS S3, and every time I upload anything but what I have done, it doesn't actually work. I am note sure why. I'm as confused as you..

Comment: Because you're decoding it twice.