# python expressions normalize('NFKD', txt)

Tags: python, typescript

i want to ask if there is expressions similar or how can i convert this expressions python

```
normalize('NFKD', txt).encode('ASCII','ignore').decode('ASCII')
```

to TypeScript.
thanks to help me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode/encode string to base64 in typescript express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56952405/how-to-decode-encode-string-to-base64-in-typescript-express-server)

Comment: @Nicolae thanks a lot for your comment , but i ask about if this expression in python means exactly because there's normalize in type script but without the ecode and decode !! do you think i need to divide the expression 'i make the normalize and after that i encode  and decode ??